# How to make postgresql user access file system?

Tags: postgresql, user-management

I am trying Postgresql for learning. I installed that from repository. by default user named postgres had created.

I want to know that how can I make this user access files in the disk?

I tried to find out from searching google but could not find clean and straightforward way

Answer (score 1):

Yes the user Postgress is like the root user of postgress, handling the daily chores of postgress, dont mess with it!

Your first postgres-job is to make urself a postgres-user, and you use that account to create your databases, and access the filesystem.